# Is There a Word Processor Where You Can Add Normally Hidden Source and Date Data per Bullet Point/Line?

Tags: microsoft-word, metadata

### Goal:

I want to be able to add metadata type information per bullet point or per line in Microsoft Word (or any word processor) that is hide-able, including the source and the day I found the information.

### Motivation:

I want to have a master document for all notes on a given subject, rather than individual documents per book or resource. Still, I want to know where I found each datum if I need to do more digging. Writing the source manually at the end of each line would clutter the document as well as be a hassle.

### What I'm envisioning:

A word file with bullet points. Being able to select all bullet points to add that metadata in some way. Being able to show/hide that metadata <strike>with a click</strike> *in some way*. While not required, being able to search for specific sources or dates would also be useful.

### What I've tried:

Only googling. Unfortunately, I was unable to find anything related to this feature through google.

Thanks for your willingness to help!

---

EDIT: If there is a program that you know of with this capability built-in, please let know. It doesn't have to be Microsoft Word.

Answer (score 1):

### In MS Word, one method would be to add your metadata as pop-up text on mouseover.

This can be done using the Hyperlink or the AutoTextList fields.

Here is my article on the Microsoft site on [Pop-Up Text in Microsoft Word](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/pop-up-text-in-microsoft-word/f070b772-7d8e-4a29-8943-bca01967cb76?tm=1609428405945). There is more on that page but this is a summary.

**Hyperlink Field**

[image: Hyperlink field screenshot]

**AutoTextList field**

> ```
> { AutoTextList “Display text” \s NoStyle \t “This is a screentip” }
> ```
>
> The syntax is: `{ AUTOTEXTLIST "Literal text" \s ["Style name"] \t ["Tip text"]`}
>
> Above is from [my free Add-in Pop-Up Text in Microsoft Word](https://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#PopUp).
>
> Here is what such a field looks like in action: [image: screenshot of AutoTextList Field display]

The AutoTextList field does not have the erroneous and confusing line about using Ctrl+Click to follow the link. However, the Hyperlink field is preserved when you convert to pdf while the AutoTextList field is not.

I am sorry, but this only gives you a way to insert the data and display it. It does not allow search but does avoid the clutter.